# Replacing key-value pair in app.config using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a app.config which looks something like this:

```
   <!-- Device Configuration goes here --> 
         <DinoConfig Alpha="aaa" Beta="bbb" Gamma="ccc" Theta="">
      <Dino Zeta="ooo" Delta="hhh" Tau="rrr" Rho="ddd" />
    </DinoConfig>
```

Now I would like to change Beta to "yyy" and Gamma to "zzz" in DinoConfig Parent node using a batch file. Also i would like to change Key-Value Pair in child nodes (Dino).

The way i'm using the batch script currently:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=^<DinoConfig Alpha="nnn" Beta="mmm" Gamma="iii" Theta=""^>"
set "dir=%temp%" & set "file=Dino.config" & pushd "!dir!"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in (%file%) do (set cstring=%%G
    if "!cstring:~6,8!"=="Beta" set "cstring=%%G"
    echo "!cstring!" | findstr /r /b /c:".*jjj.*" >nul 2>&1 && echo %string% || if defined cstring echo !cstring!
) >> %file:.config=_mod.config%
del %file% & ren %file:.config=_mod.config% %file% & popd
exit /b
```

Using this i'm changing Beta="bbb" and in next iteration i'm changing ="vvv" (it would be convinient if i can change both at once).

Comment: Can you tell me how can i achieve this.

Comment: 1. SO is not a free code writng service, so if you expect help you need to try it on your own, share your efforts and describe precisely where you are stuck; please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); 2. To process XML data you should use something that natively supports that format; batch scripting can handle text files only; treating XML as normal text is not trivial and also quite dangerous for the data to be corrupted...

Comment: I'm not new to SO, have posted questions before. I know how to code, so I just want the approach. That would suffice. Per your request, i'm updating the question above. I must say i'm not much into batch programing but i know my stuff. Thanks, for helping me if you choose to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script below works well for me. Replace *dir* and *file* values with your own, target *file* is saved in *dir*, batch file can run from a different folder:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=    ^<Dino DinoName="mmm" Key1="nnn" Key2="pqr" Key3="stu" /^>"
set "dir=%temp%" & set "file=app.txt" & pushd "!dir!"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in (%file%) do (set cstring=%%G
    if "!cstring:~6,8!"=="DinoName" set "cstring=    %%G"
    echo "!cstring!" | findstr /r /b /c:".*jkl.*" >nul 2>&1 && echo %string% || if defined cstring echo !cstring!
) >> %file:.txt=_mod.txt%
del %file% & ren %file:.txt=_mod.txt% %file% & popd
exit /b
```

It outputs to file:

```
<DinoConfig Key1="abc" Key2="def" Key3="ghi" >
    <Dino DinoName="mmm" Key1="nnn" Key2="pqr" Key3="stu" /> 
    <Dino DinoName="vww" Key1="xyz" Key2="aaa" Key3="bbb" />
</DinoConfig>
```

Alternatively, you can modify and try the script snippet you posted in the question:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('findstr...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for posting the answer :). I tried your code but new file which it creates "app.config_mod" is an empty file. and renaming from app.config_mod to app.config it encounters a syntax error at & operator just before ren command.

Comment: The problem with ren command is fixed. Looks like you cannot specify fully qualified path for file2 
ren {path}/FileName newFileName

Comment: I've added the output in the question block for formatting reasons. Please let me know if you can find errors if any coz things look ok to me but its yielding a blank app.config file.

Comment: I tried doing this but but still its yielding empty file. 
set "string="<Dino DinoName="mmm" Key1="nnn" Key2="pqr" Key3="stu" "/">"
Your script looks ok to me but i can't figure out why its yielding empty app_mod.config file

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thank You!

Comment: I've been able to do it myself with the code i shared in the question. Thanks for all the help you've given me man. I'm posting the working code in the question above for other's reference.
Thanks Again!!

Comment: I know there is a better approach like the one which you just gave me, please let me know if you know it. 
Thanks Again!

Comment: I updated the script, it works well for me. It assumes 4 spaces at start of lines with DinoName, you can adjust it in `!cstring:~6,8!` as needed. Let me know if any errors. Don't forget to replace the path value with your own. Delete all previous comments as they're not needed anymore. :)

Comment: The reason for empty file was using _path_ as dir, since its global env. var.

Comment: This is brilliant! I knew there is a better way of implementing this than how i implemented it. Thanks a million for helping me out with this Sam!! Your script is working like a cham!!! :)
I'm marking your answer as the best answer.

Comment: Yes, I've added more details to the question i asked earlier :)

Comment: Your Question formatting showing `app.conf` content got broken now.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Your script is working very well sam but the only problem i'm facing now is its also inducing string - "Echo is Off" in the config file. That's breaking the apllication. Is there a way by which i can avoid this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `Echo is off` means that a certain string value can't be calculated. What string it is - the full text? For example, if your string has 6 spaces in front of it, adjust `!cstring:~8,8!` to match it, and soon. Can you give an entire list of strings found in your .config file, or an example of the most complete .config file in your above Question? Is number of upfront spaces in strings vary in different config files?

Comment: Ah! Got it. Actually when I was updating the config file with the script. It was not able to parse the xml comments "<!-- some text -->". So I deleted all the comments which left a blank newline in the config file. So in those places it was inserting "@ECHO is off"

Comment: I updated the script. Now it ignores empty lines in .config file.

Comment: The updated script is not able to find the file. Looks like "dir=%temp%" and pushd "!dir!" is casing that problem. Ok, i'll tell you exactly how i want to change values. I have found the work around but having the correct solution will help me very much. I'm updating the Question body with the actual parameters - the xml node and the way i'm using your script.

Comment: I told you to use the updated script, and you posted the old version in the Question. Try the new one. Which file is not found? Also adjust space count in !cstring:~6,8! .

Comment: The new version is not working. After making changes when I execute the script I get this error- "system cannot find the file". I'm updating the question body with the new version, the way I'm using it.

Comment: Which file? At what point you get this message? Add Echo lines at several points to ID the cause. If you have several strings with different indent each, add a loop to calculate the indent for each string separately, or add several `IF...ELSE IF` statements.

Comment: the previous script is working fine and also replacing values. The only problem with the previous script was the spaces and comments in the xml file

Comment: The script assumes, your batch is located in a separate dir with all other batches, where you launch it from. If you've a batch collection, it makes sense. But the files you work with like %file% are placed in %temp%, or any other dir you prefer. If you keep all files in the batch dir, you don't need `pushd` and `popd` commands, since they change dir to %dir% and revert.

Comment: Brilliant! Removing pushs, popd and dir, its replacing values. for comments its replacing ! from the comments and also the spaces. That's perfect. I'll remove the comments before performing action so that's not a worry either. I just wanted to know can this script be extended to replace 2 key value pairs in the config file

Comment: I tried, its even changing the entire node for <device .... /> to <deviceConfig ... >. No problem but this will do, i'll handle the rest of the thing in my C# code. Thanks for all the help again Sam! You're the best.

Comment: Sam! Sorry to have bothored you so much. I appreciate all your help. This is the best solution i could ever imagine of based on my requirement. I do not have much hands on Batch programing but i know enough to figure out that your soulution is one of the best i could ever dream of. I have been able to achieve what i wanted with your latest updated script. Thank you very very much! I appreciate all the help you've given me. And in the process i've learnt a bit of batch programing also. Thank You!

Comment: Nice to hear this. Anytime... :)

Answer (score 0):

The code which worked for me:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=jkl"
set "replace=mmm"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%""C:\App.config""%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%""C:\NewApp.Config""%"
del c:\App.config & ren c:\NewApp.config App.config
set "search=mno"
set "replace=nnn"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "^" "%""C:\App.Config""%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%""C:\NewApp.Config""%"
del c:\App.config & ren c:\NewApp.config App.config
```